# htaccess rewrite/redirect folder

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I would like to redirect the following:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/monkey
should become
http://www.mywebsite.com/chimpansee
```

AND

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/monkey/index.html 
should become 
http://www.mywebsite.com/chimpansee/index.html
```

The following code works for the second case (with index.html). How do I get it to work for both cases?

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /monkey/
RewriteRule ^monkey/(.*) /chimpansee/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: "the following code works" - that code wouldn't do anything, it simply redirects to itself. Do you only want to redirect `index.html` or _everything_, as your code snippet suggests?

Comment: Do you have more rules in your .htaccess?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one rule should cover that-

```
RewriteRule ^monkey(/.*)?$    /chimpansee$1    [R=301,L]
```

Note that Redirect also does this kind of thing by default, e.g.

```
Redirect  301   /monkey/    /chimpansee/
```

and that avoids using mod_rewrite, which might be preferable depending where this directive is (i.e. conf or htaccess).

To limit this to only GET requests, like your code, you could use REQUEST_METHOD:

```
RewriteCond    %{REQUEST_METHOD}     ^GET$
RewriteRule    ^monkey(/.*)?$        /chimpansee$1    [R=301,L]
```

See http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/mod_rewrite-variables-cheatsheet.html for a handy list of environment variables you can use in rewrite conditions.

Comment: I think you mean `Redirect`, not `RedirectMatch`. With `RedirectMatch` you'll still need to capture a pattern and use a backreference in the target URL, since it's not prefix matching. (I think the OPs reference to `THE_REQUEST` and `GET` is just an unnecessary attempt to prevent a redirect loop - could be wrong?)

Comment: Thank you @jeremy-jones. Now I've got one a little more difficult. How do I redirect "monkey" to "_monkey_folder"? It also keeps replacing the monkey part of the destination string.

Comment: Looks like it's working now, I think my previous rule got stuck in the browser cache.