# htaccess redirect folder to subfolder

Tags: .htaccess

## Notice: I wrote the solution. Thank you anyway. :)

I know it seems duplicated question: I searched a lot, I applied tens of rewrite rules but they don't work.

I need to redirect from

```
www.domain.com/folder1
```

to

```
www.domain.com/folder1/subfolderA
```

Note: folder1 is emtpy. in subfolderA I have index.html, index.php, css file, js files. If I go to "www.doman.com/folder1/subfolderA/" I see a simple web page with correct css and js provided by index.php file.

My .htaccess file is in www.domain.com/ (I've tried to put it in folder1 but it doesn't work, even removing "RewriteBase /" line). File permssions: 0755.

"Option -Indexes","Option +Indexes" generate error "Option indexes not allowed here", so I deleted them.
"Options +FollowSymLinks" generates error "Option FollowSymLinks not allowed here" and I deleted it.

## First try: endless url

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/folder1(/.*)?$ /folder1/subfolderA$1 [L,R]
(rif: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32525136/1315873) ('R' is just for debug)
```

Results:
www.domain.com/folder1/subfolderA/subfolderA/subfolderA/subfolderA/subfolderA/

## Second try: adding a condition to stop endless loop:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !subfolderA [NC]
RewriteRule ^/folder1(/.*)?$ /folder1/subfolderA$1 [L,R]
```

Perfect for http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ but not for my server.
Results:
www.domain.com/folder1/subfolderA/subfolderA/subfolderA/subfolderA/subfolderA (unchanged)

## Third try: using $ after 'folder1'

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !subfolderA [NC]
RewriteRule ^/folder1/$ /folder1/subfolderA/ [L,R]
```

Results:
Forbidden
Log says: "No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.htm,index.php,index.php3,index.phtml,index.shtml,index.wml) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive"

If I add to the url "index.php" or "index.html" the result is "404 Not found" (that's true actually).

I don't know what else to do. I hope in your help.
It's an impossibile redirect to do?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find the right way to do :P
The .htaccess file look like this:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !subfolderA [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?folder1(/.*)?$ /folder1/subfolderA$1 [L,R]
```

As I don't wont to change url in browser (one must see "www.domain.com/folder1/"), I remove ",R" from last line.

I hope it can be of help to someone else.

Comment: .htaccess doesn't match leading slash so it has to be `RewriteRule ^/?folder1(/.*)?$ /folder1/subfolderA$1 [L]` to make it work both in Apache config and .htaccess

Answer (score 1):

You can create an index.php or index.html page in folder1 that will redirect users to subfolderA

e.g index.php can contain the following code

```
              <?php
                header("location: subfolderA");
                 ? >
```

Comment: I thought about using 'include' in php, but I think it will not find js and css files (inside subfolderA and not in folder1). If it doesn't change ulr in browser it is a solution easyer then mine! Thank you

Comment: Maybe if I understand what you are trying to achieve I can be of more help, but from what you are asking, if one is redirected to the subfolderA, then the "index.php" in that folder will display it's content to the client and that page will definitely have access to all its dependency files

Comment: Yes you are right, include won't working here. Alternative, you can use file_get_contents() to get the page from  subfolderA and then perform regex to change the url in the captured content before finally outputting it to the client. That way, you preserve the browser url and still display the page in subfolderA

Comment: I tried to use folder1/index.php file as you suggests. It works, but change also the url on browser. So for now I use my answer. :) Thank you.

Comment: Using file_get_contents can be a solution for php/html with inlined js/css. Not for js and css files included in html.